# Updating Select Case To Pull In Status From A Different Column and Conditionally Format

Tags: excel

I am currently utilizing a code snippet to conditionally format cells within Column I (Due Date) of my spreadsheet if they meet a certain date criteria.

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSlbU.jpg)

The way my code is structured now is that it will continue to keep the cells filled in red at the due date and when it has passed.

What would be the best way to update this select case to have the cells stay filled in red until a status of "Complete" from Column H is selected? Or is there a better way to go about the entire process? I would like the code to turn the due dates to green when complete has been selected.

This is the code snippet that I have been using.

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("I16:I700")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each cell In Target
icolor = 0
Select Case cell
    Case Is <= Date: icolor = 3
    Case Is <= Date + 7: icolor = 44
    Case Is <= Date + 14: icolor = 33
    Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 4
    Case Is >= Date + 31: icolor = 2
    End Select
    If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
    Next cell
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Cheers, and Thank You!

Comment: Why not use proper conditional formatting itself?

Comment: I'm trying to keep a lot of the automation VBA-based, as I'm trying to improve my skills in VBA!

Comment: If you must do it via VBA, why not just extend the Change event code?

Comment: That's a great idea; the thought didn't even cross my mind! YES! Thank you for talking me through this!